# How to trigger event on children component in specific case?

Tags: typescript, angular-material2, angular6

**Hi guys !**

I would like to use a method (example : `reset()`) of my children component on my event (example : `(closed)="el.reset()"`) who emit every time the AccordionItem is closed.

In my case, it does not work.
I provide a [StackBlitz Reproduction](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wjqql5?file=app%2Fexpansion-steps-example%2Fexpansion-steps-example.html) to share my issue.

Here [the documentation of Material Angular](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/api).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution with a little help and [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren).
For the first time, I used `@ViewChildren`.

I updated a [StackBlitz Reproduction](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wjqql5-kn2ulw?file=app%2Fexpansion-steps-example%2Fexpansion-steps-example.html) to share solution.